# pass generic function to a template

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following question:

When I pass a template function to another one it doesn't work, but when I pass a normal one to template function it compiles normally, for example:

```
template<class It, class Pred>
It findif(It begin,It end, Pred pr){
    while (begin!=end && !pr(*begin))
        begin++;
    return begin;
}
bool p(const string& s){
    /* some code */
}
```

when I pass p to findif it works,but this doesn't:

```
template<class It, class Pred>
It findif(It begin,It end, Pred pr){
    while (begin!=end && !pr(*begin))
        begin++;
    return begin;
}
template<class T
bool p(const T& s){
    /* some code */
}
```

Comment: How do you pass it?  What errors do you get?

Comment: In all likelyhood, you are trying to pass a non-instantiated template to the algo. You can't do that, templates are no callable objects. There are also no generic functions in C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver I get <unresolved overloaded function>

Comment: Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to get better help faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template functions are blueprints of a function they aren't functions per se. You must instantiate one of them so that the compiler will generate that specific instantiation. For example you can't do:

```
template<class It, class Pred>
It findif(It begin,It end, Pred pr) {
    while (begin!=end && !pr(*begin))
        begin++;
    return begin;
}

template<class T>
bool p(const T& s) {
    /* some code */
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{1,2,3}; 
  findif(v.begin(), v.end(), p);
}
```

You must first instantiate the function template for the code to be acceptable. That is, you have to provide explicitly arguments to it as:

```
  findif(v.begin(), v.end(), p<int>);
                             ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep a template and still deduce the template arguments, the normal way around that is to use a functor:

```
struct p {
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(const T& s) const { /*...*/ }
};

// ...

findif(v.begin(), v.end(), p{});
```